# How do I specify a <type> in a Grails dependency?

Tags: maven, grails, neo4j, aether

I'm using Neo4J in a Grails project.

It comes with a test class (http://neo4j.com/docs/2.1.5/tutorials-java-unit-testing.html):

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
  <artifactId>neo4j-kernel</artifactId>
  <version>2.1.5</version>
  <type>test-jar</type>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

In the Grails **BuildConfig.groovy** I'm not having any luck specifying that dependency:

```
dependencies {
    ...
    test group: 'org.neo4j',
            name: 'neo4j-kernel',
            type: 'test-jar',
            version: '2.1.5'
    ...
}
```

It's ignoring the **type** property:

```
Test.142=/Users/me/.m2/repository/org/neo4j/neo4j-kernel/2.1.5/neo4j-kernel-2.1.5.jar
```

I can't find anything in the grails or Aether docs to suggest how I incorporate the <type/>.

Can it be done?

Comment: does `test 'org.neo4j:neo4j-kernel:2.1.5:test-jar'` work?

Comment: No, I get the error: **Resolve error obtaining dependencies: Could not find artifact org.neo4j:neo4j-kernel:2.1.5:test-jar**. I've tried using **org.neo4j:neo4j-kernel:test-jar:2.1.5** too, as I wasn't sure if it was supposed to be that way around.

Comment: just for the records the format is `<groupId>:<artifactId>[:<extension>[:<classifier>]]:<version>` http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/conf.html#configurationsAndDependencies

Comment: Yes, it looks like grails doesn't support the <type/> property.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you need to use the `classifier` for this:

```
test group:"org.neo4j", 
    name:"neo4j-kernel", 
    version: "2.1.5",
    classifier:"tests"
```

Comment: Stefan! Thanks! :) That's the ticket. (Although on a side note, it looks like the classifier for the neo4j-kernel is **tests** not **test-jar**; I think that the doc (http://neo4j.com/docs/2.1.5/tutorials-java-unit-testing.html) is wrong in that regard.

Comment: oh yes, you're right it's in fact `tests` - classic copy&paste error.

Comment: Would you like me to submit a pull request, or do you have it?